# Issue with "datepicker" widget (Jquery UI) in JSP page deployed on Tomcat 7

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use `Jquery datepicker` widget in my `JSP` page but I am getting an error like :

```
$("#dateOfPurchase").datepicker is not a function--(Indicated by Firebug)
```

where `dateOf Purchase` is an input Box `type="text"` . I have included the following files(combination used one combination at a particular time) for Jquery Inclusion:

```
<script  src="resources/scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script  src="resources/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But The datepicker isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the ui scripts after the basic jquery files. Also, make sure `$("#dateOfPurchase").datepicker` is inside a document.ready block

Comment: Actually I traced the problem to the double inclusion of Jquery.<version>.js file. Which I found out after trial and error and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I traced the problem to the double inclusion of Jquery..js file. Which I found out after trial and error and solved the problem.